# How to read data from firebase based on a key value in Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I want to retrieve data from firebase using Kotlin and android studio.
This is my data class which is used to upload data into firebase:

```
class Data(var id : String,
           var productname : String , 
           var username : String,
           var phonenumber : String,
           var address: String,
           var status: String)
```

To add data to firebase, I used the following format:

```
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("orders")

val orderId :String = ref.push().key.toString()

val formdata = Data(orderId,
                    productname, 
                    username, 
                    phonenumber, 
                    useraddress, 
                    status)

ref.child(orderId).setValue(formdata).addOnCompleteListener {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Order placed sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
```

Now I want to retrieve data from firebase where the value of phone number matches the given string.

Comment: actually i suggest to index with phone_number so you will not need to phone_number match. is phone number unique in your app ?

Comment: No Kayra, phonenumber is not unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now I want to retrieve data from firebase where the value of phone number matches the given string.

To solve this, you need to use a query, like in the following lines of code:

```
val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val ordersRef = rootRef.child("orders").orderByChild("phonenumber").equalTo(givenString)
val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        for (ds in dataSnapshot.children) {
            val username = ds.child("username").getValue(String::class.java)
            Log.d(TAG, username)
        }
    }

    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()) //Don't ignore errors!
    }
}
ordersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
```

The result in your logcat, will be the user name that exist in the orders where the phone number is equal to a given string.