# Read data from Firebase and update TextView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I have to read a "show" data from Firebase and than update a TextView who ID calls "show" (yes, the same). I'm trying to do it from yesterday, but it still doesn't work.

There is some code. I was trying original documentation and other websites, but no results work. It would be great if the ID from Firebase would be random from 1 to 5.

WhiteCart.kt

```
import java.io.Serializable

data class WhiteCart(
    var show: String = "") : Serializable
```

Kalambo.kt

```
private lateinit var whiteCartShow: WhiteCart

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.game_activity)

    listener()
    nextQuest()
}

private fun nextQuest() {
    whiteCartShow = WhiteCart()

    val postListener = object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            val post = p0.getValue(WhiteCart::class.java)
        }
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            Log.w("TAG", "loadPost:onCancelled")
        }
    }
    KApp.fData.getReference("whiteCartPL/1/show").addValueEventListener(postListener)

    show.setText(whiteCartShow.show)
}
```

Firebase looks like this:

```
    {
      "whiteCartPL" : {
        "1" : { "show": "Strzykawka" },
        "2" : { "show": "Kominiarz" },
        "3" : { "show": "Lizodup" },
        "4" : { "show": "Gripowy przytulaniec" },
        "5" : { "show": "Szybka łopata" }
    }
```

Variable 'post' is never used

Comment: You cannot simply use the value of your object outside the callback. Please check the duplicate to see why do you have this behaviour and how can you solve this using a custom callback.

Comment: I tried solved my problem by this posts but it still doesn't work, that's why i type a new post. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56052718/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-based-on-a-key-value-in-kotlin
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37919455/how-to-get-string-from-firebase-realtime-db-that-contain-in-unique-key

Answer (score 0):

You aren't updating the Textview's text through the asynchronous call. The reason it says `post` isn't used, is because you aren't using it. Call `textView.setText(post.show)` in order to change the TextView's text when the data is updated in the database.

Comment: When i add "show.setText(post.show)" in onDataChange i have this error "Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type WhiteCart?" so than i do this:
```kotlin
if (post != null) {
                    show.setText(post.show)
                }
```
but than i have this error "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.asmi.game/com.asmi.game.game.Kalambo}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property fData has not been initialized". 
fData is initialized id KApp. fData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()

Comment: and in companion object { lateinit var fData: FirebaseDatabase }

Comment: You are delving into multiple problems now and using this as a resource to answer all your coding questions... I've given you the answer to your original problem.

1.) Yes, you need to null check your new value because it could be null.
2.) You don't need to hold a reference to the FirebaseDatabase instance in your Application. You can just reference it anywhere since it is a Singleton. If you are going to leave it as is. Remove the `lateinit` keyword and initialize your value there.

If you could please re-evaluate your code and select an answer, it would be appreciated.